# Redactor I source button no longer working?

Tags: redactor, config

Running Craft CMS 2.6.2903 and Redactor I 1.1.0

This is my config:

```
{
    "buttons": ["format", "bold", "italic", "lists", "image"],
    "plugins":["fullscreen", "source"],
    "toolbarFixed": true
}
```

fullscreen and source no longer work, not sure but possibly a recent Craft update? I have all my rich text fields set to Rich Text (Redactor I) and Standard as `Standard.json` is the config I edited for above settings. No html or source button shows up, fullscreen shows up but doesn't work.

Anyone know what could possibly be wrong, this config worked a while back.

Comment: The source plugin has never been included in Redactor I (https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorI/commits/e5ca05fa29ff1c6e77a75e0287cfe026b228e305/redactori/resources/lib/redactor/plugins).  Just tested fullscreen and it worked on the latest Craft 2.6.2931 and Redactor I 1.1.0 and it worked fine locally. Check your browser's console for any JS errors.

Comment: Fullscreen js error Uncaught TypeError: this.button.changeIcon is not a function http://example.com/index.php?p=admin/resources/redactori/lib/redactor/plugins/fullscreen.js&d=1473713215 I had source working before, is there not an option to view source/html etc?

Comment: html as a button doesn't work either, if you don't mind me asking what does your config look like for 1.1.0?

Comment: Maybe you just need to re-upload the Redactor I files?  Sounds like some are maybe missing. Was just using the stock configs: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorI/tree/master/config/redactor

Comment: Updated the files, still didn't work, clicked uninstall, then installed again and its back, not sure what happened.

Comment: Huh... weird.  Can you add that as an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the files, still didn't work, clicked uninstall, then installed again and its back, not sure what happened.